# Scheduling only a script to run periodically on Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, scheduled-tasks

I have a python script in Azure DevOps Pipeline which I want to run every 30 minutes.

I have written a yaml cron job which is

```
trigger: none


schedules:
- cron: "*/30 * * * *"
  displayName: Every 30 min
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  always: true
```

However, even though this runs the pipeline every 30 minutes, the script inside it is run multiple times within that 30 minutes, but I want it to run only once.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: BuildLog]

[image: BuildLog2]

This is the scheduler

[image: Scheduled Runs]

Comment: Could you please share logs and Stages/Jobs from Pipeline Execution?

Comment: I have added the BuildLog, do you also need the log stream?

Comment: I do not really see that the Python script inside Pipeline runs multiple times within that 30 minutes. Could you please point me in right place where I can see multiple executions?

Comment: I added two images, in the time stamp you can see the script output every 10 minutes

Comment: Could you please check Scheduled runs in Azure Pipelines?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-runs-view

Comment: I have attached the screenshot to show the scheduled runs (please note I changed the scheduler to run once everyday which is different from my question) but it still runs every 10 mins

Comment: Do you have also UI scheduled time triggers?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#ui-settings-override-yaml-scheduled-triggers

Comment: I had them but I deleted them and then updated the yaml file ( I know the UI one overrides the yaml file)

Comment: Just a note, the pipeline doesn't run every 10 mins, its the script inside the pipeline which keeps on running, the scheduler is doing its job correctly.

I want to know what to do so that the python script only runs once when the build is successful everyday